# Laravel Cashier invoicePrice unit_amount too high

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel Cashier 14.5.0 in my Laravel 9 project. I need to access the third argument of the `invoiceFor` method to set some custom metadata to update my project's database, to do this means having to set the second option, the `amount` argument.

I'm working with GBP currency, and am retrieving my product price from Stripe, I'm given the unit_amount in the smallest possible currency, pence, but when charged, the amount is significantly higher. What am I missing?

For exmaple:

My price is: £4.99
But I'm charged: £2,490.01

Here's my code:

```php
$productPrice = Cashier::stripe()->prices->retrieve($productOption->stripe_id);

// get user
$user = Auth::user();

$user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
$user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($request->input('token'));
$user->invoicePrice(
    $productOption->stripe_id, intval($productPrice->unit_amount), [
        'metadata' => [
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'api_key_uuid' => $apiKey->uuid,
            'quantity' => $productOption->quantity,
            'apply_credit_balance' => true
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#charge-with-invoice) what you're doing should work. When that code runs are you seeing any Stripe API requests in the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs)? I suspect the `intval()` function returning an unexpected value. Did you just try passing the `unit_amount` field from the Price object?

Comment: Hi, yeah, I tried doing that, no luck. https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/issues/1485 was closed with no help.

Comment: What does 'no luck' mean? Did you try looking for the corresponding API requests in your Stripe Dashboard as I noted? Could it be that there are other items pulled onto the invoice, increasing the total?

Comment: Looking at my invoice, it seems the second argument is being used for the quantity? So it's setting it to 499?

Comment: Seems that way, yep! You shouldn't need to pass a `unit_amount` if you're already using a `price_xxx` ID.